# Let $X$ be a metric space and $Y$ be a open set where $Y=\cup_{x \in Y} B(x, r(x)) $ The union in this theorem will have to be infinite. Why?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a metric space and $Y$ be a open set($Y \subseteq X$). Now, according to a theorem, $Y=\cup_{x \in Y} B(x, r(x)) $ i.e. $Y$ as a union of open balls. The union in this theorem will have to be infinite. Why?(this is a statement in the book Introduction to Topology by Gamelin and Greene)

Comment: I would rather ask why would it be finite/when is it finite.

Comment: The idea was ask why it is,  what it is.? I can try afterwards to work out other things.

Comment: If you don't have any specific information on your set $Y$ then, a priori it should be infinite. If $Y$ is compact, then it turns out to be different.

Comment: Well, $Y$ is given to ba an open set andis a subset of $X$.

Comment: Are you sure that you’ve given the statement correctly? Because as you’ve given it, it’s false. Let $X$ be the integers with the usual metric, $d(m,n)=|m-n|$. The set $Y=\{0,1,2\}$ is open in $X$, and $$Y=B(0,1)\cup B(1,1)\cup B(2,1)\;,$$ where the union is certainly not infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a metric space and the subspace $(0,1)\times \mathbb{R}$. Clearly you cannot cover $(0,1)\times \mathbb{R}$ with finitely many balls since each one has finite diameter, but the diameter of $(0,1)\times \mathbb{R}$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

I think they mean that the union *in general* will be infinite, as Kyle's example shows. It could well be finite. An open set could just be a single open ball (which is itself open) and we could certainly write it as a finite union of open balls. But in general it will be infiniteyou cannot write an open square as a finite union of open circles (in the plane), e.g.

One *can* show that in a separable metric space, we can reduce the number of needed open balls to a countable set. But if we pick a ball $B(x,r(x))$ for any $x \in Y$, then in a lot of spaces (like in the Euclidean spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$) different balls are going to be distinct, and we are starting out with an uncountable set of open balls.